# proper way to restrict certain events to be emittable only by by server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a socketio node service that handles the chatting mechanism of my APP. There is an event that can only be emitted by the backend server of my APP.

This is how it is currently implement:

```
if (socket.request.connection.remoteAddress === "::ffff:127.0.0.1") {
    socket.on("msg-relay", (msg, hit, receiver) => {
      socket.to(SOCKET_ID_DIR[hit]?.[receiver]).emit("msg-received", msg);
    });
  }
```

Do you see anything wrong with this? If so, what is the proper way to implement this?